# Should this unsafe code work also in .NET Core 3?

Tags: c#, stackalloc

I'm refactoring my libraries to use `Span<T>` for avoiding heap allocations if possible but as I target also older frameworks I'm implementing some general fallback solutions as well. But now I found a weird issue and I'm not quite sure whether I found a bug in .NET Core 3 or am I doing something illegal.

**The issue:**

```cs
// This returns 1 as expected but cannot be used in older frameworks:
private static uint ReinterpretNew()
{
    Span<byte> bytes = stackalloc byte[4];
    bytes[0] = 1; // FillBytes(bytes);

    // returning bytes as uint:
    return Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes.GetPinnableReference());
}

// This returns garbage in .NET Core 3.0 with release build:
private static unsafe uint ReinterpretOld()
{
    byte* bytes = stackalloc byte[4];
    bytes[0] = 1; // FillBytes(bytes);

    // returning bytes as uint:
    return *(uint*)bytes;
}
```

Interestingly enough, `ReinterpretOld` works well in .NET Framework and in .NET Core 2.0 (so I could be happy with it after all), still, it bothers me a bit.

Btw. `ReinterpretOld` can be fixed also in .NET Core 3.0 by a small modification:

```cs
//return *(uint*)bytes;
uint* asUint = (uint*)bytes;
return *asUint;
```

**My Question:**

Is this a bug or does `ReinterpretOld` work in older frameworks only by accident and should I apply the fix also for them?

Remarks:

- The debug build works also in .NET Core 3.0
- I tried to apply `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` to `ReinterpretOld` but it had no effect.

Comment: FYI: `return Unsafe.As<byte, uint>(ref bytes[0]);` or `return MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, uint>(bytes)[0];` - no need to use `GetPinnableReference()`; looking into the other bit, though

Comment: [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIGYACMhgYQYG8aHuGAHKAJYA3bBhhNySBgFcAdrmwAzcdIGyMDAEow1YqPxgYA8gBsAJgAoAlFx6dqPRw2ABPMQCpnbmLgYBeBlwMbDAAa2wTEwgwLzEAbRQAXQBuWydYnziABkT/BnJUh3SmAHYGdwtVdXcrVzFcQscAXzSGVv5hUXFiSRl5JRVdLR11GH1YY3NSa1b7YozPOp88oJDwyOiMhJTWxyXcbNyAgt2eKoxPPABVIYDK3Rr9xuLiMvdr3WfuFuomoA===) in case it helps anyone else. The two versions which avoid `Span<T>` do compile to different IL. I don't *think* you're doing anything invalid: I suspect a JIT bug.

Comment: what is the garbage that you are seeing? are you using the hack to disable locals-init? this hack *significantly* impacts `stackalloc` (i.e. it doesn't wipe the space allocated)

Comment: @canton7 if they compile to the same IL, we can't infer it is a JIT bug... if the IL is the same, etc... sounds more like a compiler bug, if anything, perhaps with an older compiler? György : can you indicate exactly how you're compiling this? what SDK, for example? I cannot repro the garbage

Comment: The SDK version number is 3.0.100. The garbage: I get different numbers for each run. I suspect that the array is not initialized with zeros in release build (though then the applied fix was illegal, too).

Comment: @canton7 oh, my bad; sorry

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg and to confirm - you aren't using the locals-init hack? also: what are the older frameworks that you want to target? span goes down to net45, for example

Comment: @MarcGravell: No other hacks than in the provided sample. I also target framework 3.5 and 4.0.

Comment: It looks like stackalloc doesn't always zero, actually: [link](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1279#issuecomment-124003439)

Comment: @canton7: Ahh, a very good finding, thank you.

Comment: @canton7 that's .... not obvious and unexpected! but indeed: "manually wipe your `stackalloc`" would seem to be the order of the day

Comment: And actually the verdict was "C# will keep zero initializing by default. Changing the default would be too breaking.". So maybe I will open a new issue for them.

Comment: @canton7 you should add an answer, IMO; I could do it, but: it is your "find"

Comment: "I also target framework 3.5 and 4.0" - I understand where you're coming from - until very recently, some of my libs offered builds right down to net20; but frankly: it is probably time to cut the ties there. My recommendation is netstandard2.0, adding net462 (or ideally, net472) and/or netcoreapp3.1 etc if there are APIs in them that you can make use of to optimize pieces

Comment: You know what you mean. I have a VS debugger component that still supports Windows XP and VS2008. Are you trying to say it's time to let them go? :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ooh, this is a fun find; what is happening here is that your local is getting optimized away - there are no locals remaining, which means that there is no `.locals init`, which means that `stackalloc` behaves **differently**, and does not wipe the space;

```cs
private static unsafe uint Reinterpret1()
{
    byte* bytes = stackalloc byte[4];
    bytes[0] = 1;

    return *(uint*)bytes;
}

private static unsafe uint Reinterpret2()
{
    byte* bytes = stackalloc byte[4];
    bytes[0] = 1;

    uint* asUint = (uint*)bytes;
    return *asUint;
}
```

becomes:

```
.method private hidebysig static uint32 Reinterpret1() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldc.i4.4 
    L_0001: conv.u 
    L_0002: localloc 
    L_0004: dup 
    L_0005: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0006: stind.i1 
    L_0007: ldind.u4 
    L_0008: ret 
}

.method private hidebysig static uint32 Reinterpret2() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
        [0] uint32* numPtr)
    L_0000: ldc.i4.4 
    L_0001: conv.u 
    L_0002: localloc 
    L_0004: dup 
    L_0005: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0006: stind.i1 
    L_0007: stloc.0 
    L_0008: ldloc.0 
    L_0009: ldind.u4 
    L_000a: ret 
}
```

I *think* I'd be happy to say that this is a compiler bug, or at least: an undesirable side-effect and behavior given that [previous decisions have been put in place to say "emit the .locals init"](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1279#issuecomment-124003439), **specifically** to try and keep `stackalloc` sane - but whether the compiler folks agree is up to them.

The workaround is: treat the `stackalloc` space as undefined (which, to be fair, is what you're meant to do); if you expect it to be zeros: manually zero it.

Comment: It seems there is an [open ticket](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23951) for this. I'm going to add a new comment to that.

Comment: Huh, all my work and I didn't notice the first was missing `locals init`. Nice one.

Comment: @canton7 if you're anything like me, you automatically skip past `.maxstack` and `.locals`, making it especially easy to not notice that that it is/isn't there :)

Comment: `The content of the newly allocated memory is undefined.` according to MSDN. The specification doesn't say that the memory should be zeroed either. So it looks like it only works on old framework by accident, or as a result of a non-contractual behaviour.